# How can I redirect process output on another form in a dll

Tags: c#, process

I am going from delphi to c #, I am a novice c#, I have this code that works well :

// Form1

```
public void Scan(string fOut)
{
    Form2 frm2;

    void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
             frm2.addItem(e.Data ?? string.Empty);
        }));
    }

    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show(this);
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
       // necessary code
        p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        while (!p.HasExited)
        {
            Application.DoEvents(); 
        }
        p.Close();
        frm2.Close();
        frm2.Dispose();
     }
}
```

// Form2

```
public void addItem(string line)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add(line);
}

private void Form2_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

I want to move the code to a dll, but I can not find a Form1 reference that calls dllname.Scan("fn.xxx"):

```
this.BeginInvoke..
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Forgive me,the solution public void Scan(Form f, string fOut). I hope the post was not useless

Comment: See my two form project.  You need to use an instance of the form.  See my answer at following posting.  You may not want to make the 2nd for invisible : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa